# AppleScript : Track change (time tracking)

Tags: applescript, logs, time, time-tracking

I have an app which display the number of minutes passed within a specific status

for e.g I'm online now since 102 min , the result of my script return `{"Online for 102:40"}`

How can I get the value of the totals minutes spend in the same status ?

e.g if I go online 10min then offline 5min, then online again 50 min
I would need to save value to get some report like :

> " Total Online time : 60min, Offline 5min  "

I wrote this for now but this only get the current value in the specific status as text.

```
repeat
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "app name"

            try 
                set mYTAuxChecker to get value of static text of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window "app name" as text
            on error
                --
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

to get the int I did this

```
set s to quoted form of mYTAuxChecker
do shell script "sed s/[a-zA-Z\\']//g <<< " & s
set dx to the result
set numlist to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of words in dx
    set this_item to word i of dx
    try
        set this_item to this_item as number
        set the end of numlist to this_item
    end try
end repeat
```

and to get the world I made this

```
set mYTAuxCheckerAsText to first word of mYTAuxChecker
```

but then how can I summarise each statues and sum the total

Comment: _"I know that my approach don't make much sense"_  That's honestly the only part of the question that did make sense.  Any way you can edit your question and try and explain it in a different way ?  And please tell us what app it is you are using—it's next to impossible to provide assistance otherwise.

Comment: I did but it's probably to complex anyway